# Load More Json data when ScrollView reaches to bottom (Client & Server Side ) in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, scrollview

Lets say I have 100 json data and 50 data instantiated when application starts, now I have to instatiate more data when I scroll down and it reaches to bottom as shown in gif image below.

Please help, I have no idea how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic filling of a scrollview with on-demand loading, you would need to know when your scrollview is at the bottom and check if it can load any items.

I have used a similar approach for an inventory system, where the amount of items in your inventory can be practically infinite. And you do not want to load an infinite amount of items obviously.

```
// 0.025f works for me, it determines the sensitivity of how close to the bottom you would need to be
if (_scrollRect.normalizedPosition.y < 0.025f && _hasItems)
{
    // Check for additional items and add them to your scrollview
    YourMethod();
    // If there are no more items to be loaded, set a class variable
    _hasItems = false;
}
```

You would need to build your own logic around this code and set `_hasItems` to true upon start or something similar.

Comment: If it is infinite, I'll recommend to implement not just a method to load the new ones, but also a method to free all that memory information from old ones. So you only store on memory a fraction of your infinity list, the fraction you see.

Comment: @Lotan I agree with you,. I had some solution add below : `_scrollRect.normalizedPosition.y < -0.026f` so final if will be : `if (_scrollRect.normalizedPosition.y < 0.025f && _hasItems && _scrollRect.normalizedPosition.y < -0.026f)`